# Prestashop logout user programmatically

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am developing a module in Prestashop. I want to know how to logout user programmatically, and how can I redirect a user to custom url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
$customer->logout();
```

Or

```
$customer->mylogout();
```

The first one is a complete logout, the second one will leave affiliate information in customer's cookies.

Both methods fire `actionCustomerLogoutBefore` and `actionCustomerLogoutAfter` hooks, so you can attach to them for your redirect.

Speaking of redirect - it depends on what page you want to redirect your customers to, if it's an internal page, you can use either:

```
$redirect_link = Context::getContext()->link->getPageLink(...); // or "getModuleLink", etc., see classes/Link.php for details.
```

Or

```
$redirect_link = $this->context->link->getPageLink(...);
```

You would then use either `redirect`, `redirectLink` or `redirectAdmin` (probably the other two, as redirectAdmin only makes sense if you're in Back Office) of `Tools` class to redirect to that link.